# datetimepicker jquery-ui autoclose when onlcik event

Tags: datetimepicker

jquery-ui datetimepicker autoclose in onclick event

In the below example, i can close the date picket by clicking on "Done" button

http://jsfiddle.net/8xjhjssm/4/

But when i add feww css code to remove done button, and expecting to close the datepicker when the date is selected, it does not work, below is the example

http://jsfiddle.net/8xjhjssm/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the onSelect function**
you can use the function `$.datepicker._hideDatepicker()` to hide all pickers or `$.datepicker._hideDatepicker(inputElm)` to hide specific picker.

```
onSelect: function (date, obj) {        
        $.datepicker._hideDatepicker(obj.input[0]);
}
```